# android app launching error on some devices

Tags: android, kotlin

```
06/14 10:51:04: Launching 'app' on Pixel 2 API 27.
$ adb shell am start -n "com.wordsforfun.wordsforplay/com.wordsforfun.words.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Error while executing: am start -n "com.wordsforfun.wordsforplay/com.wordsforfun.words.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.wordsforfun.wordsforplay/com.wordsforfun.words.MainActivity }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {com.wordsforfun.wordsforplay/com.wordsforfun.words.MainActivity} does not exist.

Error while Launching activity
```

1)my android app runs on version 9 it lags in version 6 but it gets crashed in android version 7,8 .
2)please can anyone help this i am new to android studio
3)now doing many experiments i have changed my starting activity to other activity then it is working i will a providing the main activity content here

```
main activity

package com.wordsforfun.words


import android.content.Intent
import android.media.MediaPlayer
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.Menu
import android.view.MenuItem
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.Switch
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var mp:MediaPlayer
    lateinit var mp2:MediaPlayer
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        var btn = findViewById<Button>(R.id.start)
        var btn2=findViewById<Button>(R.id.btn2)
        val mySwitch=findViewById<Switch>(R.id.switch1)
        mySwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener { buttonView, isChecked ->
            if(isChecked) {
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(this@MainActivity, resources.getIdentifier(btn.tag as String, "raw", packageName))
                if(mp.isPlaying)
                {
                    return@setOnCheckedChangeListener
                }
                else {
                    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this@MainActivity, resources.getIdentifier(btn.tag as String, "raw", packageName))
                    mp.start()
                }
            }
            else{
                mp.stop()
            }
        }
        btn.setOnClickListener {
            mp2= MediaPlayer.create(this@MainActivity,resources.getIdentifier(btn2.tag as String,"raw",packageName))
            mp2.start()

            var intent = Intent(this@MainActivity,actual_file::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }

    }


    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        val inflater2=menuInflater
        inflater2.inflate(R.menu.customfile2,menu)
        return true
    }
    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        when (item?.itemId) {
            R.id.instructions -> {
                val intent10= Intent(this@MainActivity,instructions::class.java)
                startActivity(intent10)
                return true
            }
            R.id.moreinfo -> {
                val intent11= Intent(this@MainActivity,more_info::class.java)
                startActivity(intent11)
                return true
            }

        }
        return true
    }

}
```

```
this is my xml of main activity




<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.wordsforfun.words.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:tag="click"
        android:text="Button"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/p11" />

    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/switch1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Music"
        android:textColor="#43034E"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/p11"
        android:src="@drawable/r" />

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/a"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        app:cardCornerRadius="50dp"
        app:cardElevation="50dp"
        app:cardMaxElevation="50dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/start"
            android:layout_width="200sp"
            android:layout_height="60sp"
            android:background="@drawable/y1"
            android:tag="start"
            android:text="Play"
            android:textSize="36sp"
            android:textStyle="italic" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView6"
            android:layout_width="200sp"
            android:layout_height="60sp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/y1" />
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually got it i have used 2 images 0f 800kb in first activity so it was crashing

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the name of the activity from manifest.xml file

If it looks like this:

```
<activity android:name="MainActivity">
```

Add a period to the beginning of the Activity's name:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
```

**OR**

Add the package name to the beginning of the Activity's name:

```
<activity android:name="com.wordsforfun.words.MainActivity">
```